# Upload to S3 with Node/Express

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-s3

When I go through this process below to upload to S3 using aws-sdk and Node/Express I get no errors and land on the "successfully uploaded" page. However the new file does not show up in my amazon bucket. Where am I going wrong?

Thank you for any help!

```
var aws             = require('aws-sdk');
var multerS3        = require('multer-s3');
var  multer          = require("multer");



aws.config.update({
    secretAccessKey: 'MYKEY',
    accessKeyId: 'MYKEY',
    region: 'us-east-2'
});

var s3 = new aws.S3();

var upload = multer({
  storage: multerS3({
    s3: s3,
    bucket: 'medstayfiles',
    metadata: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, {image: file.fieldname});
    },
    key: function (req, file, cb) {
      cb(null, Date.now().toString())
    }
  })
})
```

Posting:

```
router.post('/', upload.array('photos', 1), function(req, res, next) {
  res.send('Successfully uploaded')
})
```

Form:

```
<form action="/rentals" method ="POST"> 
<input type="file" name="image" id="image">
<div class="form-group"> <button>Submit!</button> </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Look to your network tab. Is the file even being sent to the server? *(it shouldn't be)*

Comment: Second question: are you viewing the correct region in AWS? You're posting to US East, if you're checking S3 in a different region, then you won't see your files.

Comment: Hey Kevin, I'm not sure how to check that.

Comment: F12, click network. submit the form, click the request that was made, read request body. Oh, and check the preserve logs checkbox (google chrome)

Comment: Kevin it looks like it is posting correctly. "Status Code:200 OK"

Comment: @Lirik Yeah viewing in the same region. Amazon URL has "region=us-east-2"

Comment: Update: Now I am getting the error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined" however the image is passing through the console.log()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Not exactly sure what was causing the error but this fixed it:

On the form I added enctype="multipart/form-data" so:

```
<form action="/rentals" method ="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

I also changed the metadata to the following:

```
var upload = multer({
    storage: multerS3({
        s3: s3,
        bucket: 'mybucketname',
        key: function (req, file, cb) {
            var fileExtension = file.originalname.split(".")[1];
            var path = "uploads/" + req.user._id + Date.now() + "." + fileExtension;
            cb(null, path); 
        }
    })
});
```

That did the trick for me!